# A question related to the Minkowski sum

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

In the context of geometry, the Minikowski sum of convex sets $A$ & $B$ is defined as,

$A+B$={$a+b | a\in A,b\in B$}.

As an illustration of this concept, we can consider the Minkowski sum of an origin-symmetric square $K$ of side length $l$ and a disk $L = \epsilon B$ of radius $\epsilon$,that is centered at $0$ ($B$ is the unit ball). Now, the total area of the combined object, say $V(K+L)$, which consists of,

1. A rounded square composed of a copy of $K$,
2. Four rectangles of area $l \epsilon$,
3. Four quarter disks of radius $\epsilon$.

Note: Assume these objects are in the Euclidean plane.

My question:

why is the combined object a rounded square? What is the intuition behind Minkowski sum(in the context of geometry)?.

Comment: You may want to write Euclidean plane for clarity.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh I've indicated it.

Comment: You only infer it from context like square, area etc. I am saying change "Euclidean space" to "Euclidean plane". Also, note, in higher dimensions a similar decomposition takes place.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Oh yeah..sorry for being careless.Fixed it.

Comment: Notice what happens for $n$ sided convex polygons. You get a copy of the object, $n$ small rectangles and the curved edges always give a disk when glued together.

Comment: Suppose your convex shapes have interior, you can pick a point inside, say $a\in A$ say and $b\in B$. So now, $A+B$=$(a+b)+A'+B'$. Where $A'$ and $B'$ contain zero. So up to translation, it suffices to consider convex shapes containing zero.

Comment: What happens when you add two scaled versions of the same set to itself?

Comment: What happens when you add an $m$ gon to an $n$ gon in generic position?

Comment: The best way to gain an intuition is to ask questions examples or classes of examples you can calculate.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Is this process of combining convex objects a unique one?. Similarly, is the process of decomposing a given convex object/shape into multiple convex objects a unique one?

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh \\What happens when you add an m gon to an n gon in generic position?\\


This is exactly what I'm trying to understand. The resultant object should be convex. So, how can we construct such an object by two different convex shapes. In my case, it's a disk & a square. Obviously, these rounded corners are due to the disk. But, why does it only act upon corners?.

Comment: If $A$ is the convex hull of $a_1,...,a_m$ and $B$ is the convex hull of $b_1,...,b_n$ then $A+B$ is the convex hull of $a_i+b_j, 1\leq i\leq m, 1\leq j \leq n$. Presumably, you want to express the new extreme points in terms of the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) **I answer first to your final question** "what is the intuition behind Mikowski sum ?"

The  shapes I will consider are convex polygons, with notations

$$  A = A_1A_2\cdots A_m \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ B= B_1B_2\cdots B_n$$

(we assume a cylic numbering convention $A_{m+1}=A_1$, etc.)

I am aware of 3 different ways to consider  Minkowski sum $ A \oplus B$ :

1) (fig. 1 : left) by considering the sum of all vectors

$$\vec{OC_{p,q}}:=\vec{OA_p}+\vec{OB_q}$$ for a certain origin point $O$ and then taking the convex hull (featured in green) of all points $C_{p,q}$ represented by little stars (the convex hull of a set of points is the smallest convex set containing all these points).

**Remark** The choice of origin point $O$ is unimportant : changing it into $O'$ results in a simple translation by vector $\vec{OO'}$ meaning that we have the same result ($A \oplus B$ is defined up to a translation).

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Two ways to build the Minkowski sum.*

2) (Fig. 1 : right) By defining it as the (green) shape "halfway from $A$ and $B$" (up to a proper normalization) in an operation called "morphing between shapes" with notation $\tfrac12(A+B)$.

3) (Fig. 2) still another way, by working on **borders** : consider the two families of vectors $A_{p+1}-A_p=\vec{A_pA_{p+1}}$  and $\vec{B_qB_{q+1}}$, merge them into a big bunch of vectors, call them $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \cdots \vec{v_{m+n}}$, then do the inverse operation by constructing the shape whose "borders" are

$$\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_1}+\vec{v_{2}}, \vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}+\vec{v_{3}}, \cdots$$

You get in this way the borderline of Minkowski sum of $A$ and $B$.

Remark : the first operation is akin to a derivation, the second one, its inverse,  to an integration.

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Constructing $A \oplus B$ in a third way.*

B)  (Fig. 3) Now, for the issue about the **Minkowski sum of a polygon and a disk** $rB$ with radius $r$, where $B$ is the unit disk (a disk can be considered as the limit of regular polygons with $n$ sides when $n \to \infty$) and the formula of its area :

$$area( A \oplus rB)=area(A)+Lr+\pi r^2\tag{1}$$

($A \oplus rB$ is called the dilated set in the domain of "mathematical morphology/computational geometry). The vizualisation of the decomposition into elementary areas presented under the following form is a model of graphical proof... I wish this figure helps you in the full understanding about the rounded parts.

[image]

*Fig. 3 : A visual proof for formula (1)*

Remark : for more, here is an excellent [source](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/).

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer!!

So, this process of combining convex objects a unique one? (Because of the method 1, you've mentioned) . But, is the process of decomposing a given convex object/shape into multiple convex objects a unique one?

Comment: No, no uniqueness in general. You can have different decompositions of a same polygon : $A \oplus B=A' \oplus B'= \cdots$ : it's easy to see why by using method 3: being given a certain bunch of arrows, we can can be partition it into 2 separate bunches in (many) different ways...