# How to visualise this weighted combination?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, polytopes, non-convex-optimization

Let $x_1, ..., x_n$ be a set of real numbers. The convex polytope formed from $x_1, ..., x_n$ is given by the set of all $$\sum_i \alpha_i x_i,$$ where $\alpha_i \geq 0$ satisfy $\sum_i \alpha_i =1$.

Suppose instead, however, that we consider the weighted combination $$\sum_i \alpha_i x_i,$$ where $\alpha_i \in [0,1]$. That is, we drop the assumption that $\sum_i \alpha_i$.

> Does anyone have any advice/tools for visualising this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume in a first step that the $x_i$s are vectors of $\mathbb{R^2}$ (as you are mentionning the word polytope). What you are describing is a [zonohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron) which is defined either as the polygon defined by the so-called Minkowski sum of $n$ line segments (see graphics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533500)) or the projection into $\mathbb{R^2}$ of the hypercube/tesseract of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Now, as you are in $\mathbb{R^1}$ (the $x_i$s are a set of real numbers), project again the obtained 2D shape onto any axis.