# Extending geometry problem to n dimensions

Tags: geometry

I know the classic problem of finding the locus of points that are a unit distance away from a rectangle with length $L$ and width $W$.

More specifically, we obtain a rectangle with four quarter-circles in the corners.

We can define a similar problem for a $2$ dimensional surface in $3$-space: namely, the locus of points a unit distance from a rectangular prism. If I am not mistaken, we obtain eight eighth-spheres, twelve quarter-cylinders, and a rectangular prism "fused" together.

Extending the problem to higher dimensions, what shapes do we have? On a similar note, how can we express the hypervolume of the points for the case of the manifold with dimensions $\{W, L, H, X\}$, where $X$ is the fourth dimension? And is there a general formula for an $n$-dimensional manifold with dimensions $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n\}$?

Comment: This looks like a good start. It is certainly possible to continue to higher dimensions. How far can you continue on your own? Note that even a plane you are not attaching quarter-circles to a rectangle; you are cutting notches in the four corners and putting quarter-circles there, or you might say you are putting smaller rectangles along the edges of a rectangle and then filling the gaps with quarter-circles, which may be a better way to extend the construction.

Comment: I know we have sixteenth sixteenths of a hypersphere since we have 16 vertices on the object. I also conjecture part of the formula will be WLHX + 2WLH + 2WHX + 2LHX + 2WLX. Then I get stuck. I know i must implement the edges and faces somehow

Comment: The most natural context in which one can study this kind of stuff is "Minkowski addition" (of convex shapes) which can be defined in nD. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3533500/305862)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the description of a general case below is accurate, but a full proof is both simple and too long to post here. I.e., it is left as an exercise to the reader.

Let's assume that cuboid $C$ is centered at the origin and has dimensions $2a_k$, so it can be defined as a set of points $C = \left\{ (x_1, ..., x_n)\;|\; -a_k \leq x_k \leq a_k\right\}$

The border of a cuboid $C$ in $\mathbb R^n$ can be represented as a union of $k$- dimensional cuboids where $0\leq k<n$.

Cuboids are convex, so any point $\mathbf p$ at distance 1 has a unique point $\mathbf q$ on the border of $C$ such that $|\mathbf p - \mathbf q|$ = 1.

Since $\mathbf q$ is on the border we know it must belong to some $n-m$-dimensional face $B$ of $C$, where $0 < m \leq n$.  I.e., there is a subset $I_B$ of $m$ indices such that

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
q_i  =  b_i   & \mbox{if} & i \in I_B
\\
-a_i < q_i < a_i & \mbox{if} & i \notin I_B
\end{array}
$$
where $b_i = \pm a_i$.

For a given $\mathbf q$ the set $K_q$ of all $\mathbf p$'s such $|\mathbf p-\mathbf q|= 1$ can be described as $\frac{1}{2^{m}}$-th part (``octant''?) of $(m-1)$-dimensional sphere:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
p_i  =  q_i & \mbox{if} & i \notin I_B
\\
\sum_{j\in I_B} (p_i-b_i)^2 = 1
\;\wedge\;
b_i (p_i - b_i) > 0
& \mbox{if}
& i \in I_B
\end{array}
$$

The set $K_B$ of all $p$'s that are at distance 1 from face $B$ can now be described as

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
-a_i < p_i < a_i & \mbox{if} & i \notin I_B
\\
\sum_{j\in I_B} (p_i-b_i)^2 = 1
\;\wedge\;
b_i (p_i - b_i) > 0
& \mbox{if}
& i \in I_B
\end{array}
$$
and the set $K$ of all points at distance 1 from $C$ is simply a union:
$$
K = \bigcup_B K_B
$$

Comment: As I have made the remark above, these issues have been well studied in the framework of Minkowski sum, Minkowski functionals, etc.

Comment: It is true that $K$ can be represented as the border of the Minkowski sum of $C$ and $n$-dimensional unit disk, but I thought it is worth posting a more explicit/detailed description.